# Python Incremental Bar without max

Tags: python

I want to use IncrementalBar in my script but I don't know the max value if I leave it by default it takes 100 what should I put?
The values in my script are changeable some time 20,16, 120
Any help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe provide a [mre]. It's hard to understand your problem like this

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Since its changeable you have to pass a variable to `max_value` parameter like so for example:

```
import progressbar

value = 20  # 16, 120
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=value)
...
```

Write more details on what you're using and provide the code you wrote, so people can help you.